# Does PostgreSQL have any column which maintains uniqueness between table rows like as oracle has rowId and rowNum?

Tags: postgresql

In oracle DB we can display rowid & rownum with table column, but in PostgreSQL does anything can we display along with table column?

Ex: select rowid, rownum,id_mytable from mytable;

Comment: Note that `rownum` is not "unique" for a single table in Oracle. The value for rownum depends on the **query** that is being run. It is not stored anywhere and will change across different executions of the. Even the `rowid` can change.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`ctid` column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html):

```
SELECT ctid, * 
FROM some_table 
LIMIT 10;
```

There is window function `row_number() over()`, but it doesn't return row identifier, it is only numbers of rows in query results.

Comment: pg_class is related to PostgreSQL catalogs table not to corresponding user define table.

Comment: @AnandKumar: `ctid` is present in **every** table (as explained in the link that Jan included)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oid should be unique for each row in table.